# Paley-Wiener-Zigmund Integral definition

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I have seen the Paley-Wiener-Zigmund integral given as follows:

$(*) \displaystyle \int_0^1 fdW_t = W_1f(1) -\int_0^1 f'(t)W_tdt $ where $f$ is such that $f'$ is continuous and $W_t$ is Brownian motion.

Further, seems it is sometimes (perhaps often) taken that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$.

Visually it is clear this is an integration-by-parts type formula.

In part 1 of [PWZ Integral](https://sites.duke.edu/probabilityworkbook/paley-wiener-zygmund-integral/) it states for the above $(*)$ to be proven.

My question is how is this proven?

It is clear it is integration-by-parts motivated, problem is that $W_t$ is nowhere differentiable with probability $1$. Meaning I can't directly just apply IBP.

If either someone has a link to where this is proven or an explanation would be appreciated.

Other places I have seen it stated as a definition rather than something needing to be proved. Hence part of the confusion for me.

Comment: You can just use the Ito's formula for the function $g(t,x)= f(t)x$. Or the IBP formula for semimartingales, etc.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen using the integration by parts for semi-martingales there is only + signs, where does the subtraction come from. This also means I need to show $f$ is a semi-martingale.

Comment: So, I guess you did not put enough time to understand that formula as well as the definition of semimartingale

Comment: You can just change side some terms in IBP formula to see the subtraction.

Comment: The fact that f is a semimartingale is free because $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen it was simple mistake concerning the signs which I see now, I don't see the benefit of your 'So, I guess...' comment above. I still don't immediately see how $f$ being continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$ makes it a semimartingale.

$f$ being a semi-martingale means we can write it as $f = M+A$ where $M$ is a local martingale and $A$ is an adapted Cadlag process with bounded variation. Could you please explain this?